# How to use Java Annotation to create Sqlite DB column names in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, annotations

I am working on Android platform. I am using POJO class to create the Sqlite DB field names.

e.x.

```
class Provider {
    int id;
    String data;
    String value;
}
```

Based on the above POJO class, 3 fields with the given name will be generated at SQlite DB.But i want to create the name of fields(Column) different name into Sqlite DB.

e.x.

```
class Provider {
    @Annotation(FieldNameInDB = loginId)
    int id;

    @Annotation(FieldNameInDB = providerData)
    String data;

    @Annotation(FieldNameInDB = providerValue)
    String value;
}
```

Above POJO class having annotation and also the column names has been given using annotation, whatever the names being used needs to be created as column names **(loginId,providerData,providerValue)**.

So, SQLite DB will have 3 columns named as  **(loginId,providerData,providerValue)**.

Please provide solution using Java Annotation to create Custom Column names into SQLite DB and using custom names, we can retrieve the values from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it out:

```
@DatabaseField(columnName="providerData")
private String data;
```